# cherrypy jsondecoder not found

Tags: python, cherrypy

I tried this example:

```
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    @cherrypy.tools.json_out()
    def getrange(self, limit=4):
        return list(range(int(limit)))

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

when I run this, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dev/BaronPOS/baronpos/Server/tester.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cherrypy
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from cherrypy._cpcompat import urljoin as _urljoin, urlencode as _urlencode
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cpcompat.py", line 244, in <module>
    json_decode = json.JSONDecoder().decode
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONDecoder'
```

and I have absolutely no idea why. I have checked if the module is present and the class and both are. Please help!

Comment: It is Version 2.7.1 and cherrypy is installed from CherryPy-3.2.0-py2.win32.exe

Comment: Do you have simplejson installed? Try "import simplejson"

Comment: Sounds like your json module might be corrupt then. Can you try "import json / print json.JSONDecoder" ?

Comment: No gives the same error: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Dev/BaronPOS/baronpos/Server/tester.py", line 2, in <module>
    print json.JSONDecoder
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'JSONDecoder'

Comment: But, when I try it from the commandline it does work !? Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Nov 27 2010, 18:30:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> print json.JSONDecoder
<class 'json.decoder.JSONDecoder'>
>>>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out.

I was using SimpleJSONRPCServer previously (http://www.freenet.org.nz/dojo/pyjson/) but decided to move to a more flexible REST compatible architecture.

Apparantly I left an artifact called json.py, which was causing this...